# Animated logo in a web page

Tags: html, css

I came through [this](http://jip.io/) site.When the users clicks on `Log in` ,the logo on the page starts animating.How to implement such animations.I am looking for links that would be helpful.I tried googling without any success as I am not sure what it is called ?

Comment: Don't see any animations on IE10 on windows 7?

Comment: IE is the only browser you have ?

Comment: LOL. I have 11 browsers not including NCSA Mosaic and Netscape Navigator and 5 out of them have at least 4 versions. I am just too lazy to test "your problem" in all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this should be pretty straightforward.  Assuming the two are siblings, you can even do this with CSS.

**CSS APPROACH**

```
#site-logo {
   background-image: url(path/to/non-animated-image);
}
.login-button {
  /* Login default CSS here */
}
.login-button:active ~ #site-logo {
   background-image: url(path/to/animated-image.gif);
}
```

And then use an animated gif in the `.login-button:active ~ .site-logo` block.

Otherwise, you can use jQuery or something similar

**jQuery Approach**

```
.login-button.on('click', function(){
   $('#site-logo').css('background-image', 'url(path/to/animated-image.gif)');
});
```

Comment: And there you go. Wonder how many browsers he had? +1

Comment: I know _I've_ only got IE10.  I like to keep my computer *clean*.

Comment: Heheheh. Since when did having IE (ouch) makes a computer clean!

Comment: Good solution! Just one thing: Isn't `:active` just set during mouse-down?

Comment: Yeah, technically.  I suppose you could set `:focus` as well.  However, the CSS solution is just a demonstration that this sort of thing isn't that complicated.  I'd personally choose the jQuery approach for consistency/cross-browser-compatibility's sake.

Answer (score 2):

The link you posted uses CSS3 animations / transitions and a canvas. And it uses a little too much fluf for my taste to achieve such a simple effect on that logo. This is not very efficient, and as Josh Burgess pointed out, you could easily do the same thing with a .gif image. However, I just wanted to highlight some of the things you see happening in this logo. (It uses a canvas, this might simply contain a gif image, but there's more to the logo than just that).

I'll start with the basics of the circles you see, those are not images. You could use .gif images to achieve a similar effect. But in this case it's all CSS and HTML for the static part of the logo.

### An example of the circles

#### CSS:

```
.myCircles li, .myCircles li:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    list-style: none;/* hide the list style */
    text-indent: -9001em;/* hide the text content */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
    border-top: 5px solid #000;
    border-right: 5px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    /* The transition effect */
    transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 2s; /* Opera */
}
.myCircles li:after {
    content: ''; /* important to add this, without a content propperty set :before / :after psuedo elements will not show */
    left: 25px;
}
.myCircles li:hover {
    transform: rotate(190deg);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<ul class="myCircles">
    <li id="circle"> circle </li>
</ul>
```

On the website, the multiple circles are created with the :before, and :after selectors. As shown in the example above. When the animation start after clicking the button on the website, it will fade in a canvas containing that animation. For the sake of demonstration; you can add a simple :hover to see this fading effect. (fading out instead of fading in in this example.)

You could use these transitions and animations on certain other events than just a :hover (or :focus :active etc), but you will need JS to do so. For example an onclick or a load event.

#### HTML/JS (jQuery):

```
<button id="test">login</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#test').click(function() {
            $('#circle').css( 'left', '100px' );
            $('#circle').css( 'opacity', '0.5' );
        });

    });
</script>
```

These are the basics to the effect you see in the logo. However, I wouldn't recommend going trough the trouble of using the canvas in between there. But when using the canvas you have more freedom in the content you render, so for complex animations a canvas can come in handy. When using a canvas, you should prepare to create a lot of animations manually, or search for libraries to make use of the real power of a canvas element.

As for links regarding animations and the effects you wanted to know more about:
(Since this is my first post on SO it seems i can only provide you with 2 links, I'd advise you to look into css transforms and key frame animation syntax as well on CSS tricks to learn more about the possibilities of animations)

### CSS transforms, transitions, animations:

[CSS Transformations](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)

### Canvas:

[Canvas animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Basic_animations?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations)

Comment: .+ 1 for actually doing the work involved in this one. Interesting approach to say the least, but seemingly heavy-handed for what it does and not very backwards compatible to boot. Good on you for parsing that all out though. Awesome!